# Reason for specifying height on inline span element

Tags: html, css

I just wonder is it really any point to specify a height on the span element when this is a inline element.
The appearance doesn't change no matter what value I set on the height for the span selector.

Here is the complete markup and css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <title>Relative Positioning</title>
        <style type = "text/css">
           p            
           {
              font-size: 1.3em;
              font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; 
           }
           span        
           { 
              color: red;
              font-size: .6em; 
              height: .6em;
           }
           .super      
           { 
              position: relative;
              top: -1ex; 
           }
           .sub        
           { 
              position: relative;
              bottom: -1ex; 
            }
            .shiftleft  
            { 
               position: relative;
               left: -1ex; 
            }
            .shiftright 
            { 
               position: relative;
               right: -1ex; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <p>The text at the end of this sentence 
          <span class = "super">is in superscript</span>.
       </p>

       <p>The text at the end of this sentence
          <span class = "sub">is in subscript</span>.
       </p>

       <p>The text at the end of this sentence
          <span class = "shiftleft">is shifted left</span>.
       </p>

       <p>The text at the end of this sentence
          <span class = "shiftright">is shifted right</span>.
       </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

//Tony

Comment: @brbcoding actually the `span`'s height is set with `em`. But yea, many other things use `ex` which means nada.

Comment: Yeah, I thought OP was asking why those examples didn't work (why they didn't look like subscripts, superscripts, etc...) and it was because of the positioning (or lack thereof) of the other classes (`.super, .sub`, etc.)

Comment: @brbcoding @powerbuoy: Of course `ex` is a unit.  See http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html

Comment: I stand corrected. You say it as if you use `ex` every day... "The ex unit is rarely used. Its purpose is to express sizes that must be related to the x-height of a font."... Sounds like I should have said you *shouldn't* use `ex` as your unit of measure. Also, what's the support for the `ex`?

Answer (score 3):

As long as the `<span>`-element is defined as an `inline`-element ([its default](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Generic_containers_-_the_div_and_span_elements#Inline_versus_block)) the value for height won't have an effect.

From the w3.org specs [10.5 Content height: the 'height' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property):

> This property does not apply to non-replaced [inline](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes) elements. See [the section on computing heights and margins for non-replaced inline elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced) for the rules used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Span is an in-line element. So it doesn't use height property. If you want to specify any kind of height,Use CSS like `display:inline-block` !